# Rest API Multisite Site List?

Tags: multisite, rest-api

I have a multisite and I’m able to use the rest api for posts/tags/etc for specific sites but I was wondering if there’s a away to get a list of sites on the network using the rest api?

something like this: [REST API for Multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205354/rest-api-for-multisite) but without a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in endpoint for sites on a multisite network. 
You can easily create a new custom route for your api adding it to your functions.php:

```
function my_api_custom_route_sites() {
  $args = array(
    'public'    => 1, // I only want the sites marked Public
    'archived'  => 0,
    'mature'    => 0,
    'spam'      => 0,
    'deleted'   => 0,
  );

  $sites = wp_get_sites( $args );
  return $sites;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'sites', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_api_custom_route_sites'
  ]); 
});
```

This will output all sites in your network if you access: "/wp-json/wp/v2/sites".
You can create any custom endpoint without any plugin.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in endpoint for sites on a multisite network. As can be seen in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/), the built-in endpoints are:

```
+----------------+-------------------+
| Posts          | /wp/v2/posts      |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Post Revisions | /wp/v2/revisions  |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Categories     | /wp/v2/categories |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Tags           | /wp/v2/tags       |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Pages          | /wp/v2/pages      |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Comments       | /wp/v2/comments   |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Taxonomies     | /wp/v2/taxonomies |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Media          | /wp/v2/media      |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Users          | /wp/v2/users      |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Post Types     | /wp/v2/types      |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Post Statuses  | /wp/v2/statuses   |
+----------------+-------------------+
| Settings       | /wp/v2/settings   |
+----------------+-------------------+
```

Accessing sites via a REST API endpoint will require a plugin. Either one you'd write yourself, or one that's already available.